# Python multi layer dot notation

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to get a set of python classes built to simplify the sending and receiving of information over a socket connection.

I've had success using a getter and setter via the @property.

I would like the code to be in a dot notation such as:

```
class dc_load_fake_socket:

    @staticmethod
    def sendall(msg):
        print(msg)

    @staticmethod
    def recv(size):
        return 'Dummy Info'


class test_equipment:
    def __init__(self, TCP_IP, TCP_PORT=2101, BUFFER_SIZE=1024):
        self.TCP_IP = str(TCP_IP)
        self.TCP_PORT = TCP_PORT
        self.BUFFER_SIZE = BUFFER_SIZE
        self.dc_load_socket = dc_load_fake_socket

    def sendall(self, message):
        message = f'{message}\n'
        self.dc_load_socket.sendall(message.encode())

    def recv(self):
        return self.dc_load_socket.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE)

    def query(self, message):
        self.sendall(message)
        return self.recv().strip('\n')

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        return self.query("MEASure:VOLTage?")


dcl = test_equipment('192.168.0.2')

print(dcl.voltage)
```

While this works, the issue is the fact that this isn't the only 'subsystem' that uses voltage.

Ideally I would like it to act like this:
`dcl.measure.voltage`
`dcl.fetch.voltage`
`dcl.spec.voltage`
`dcl.spec.voltage = 1.5`

I've looked at using inner classes but I'm not able to use the recv(), sendall() and query() of the main class.

Originally this was done in a python file with only functions. But I ran into an issue were I actually needed two of them. I started turning this into a class as a way to make it easier to maintain, and at the same time had to update from python 2.7 to 3

I'm not the most experienced in python and any help with this would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: one hacky way to implement this using inner classes is making the inner class take the parent object in its constructor and put it in self.parent, and then redefine voltage inside the child to call voltage defined by the self.parent.voltage, however this is very hacky and not recommended at all.

Comment: I would recommend you use RabbitMQ and Python for communication. Also when writing class write in camelcase, instead test_equipment write TestEquipment